# What impact does water vapour have on incoming solar radiation?

Tags: thermodynamics

About 55% of solar radiation at TOA (ie ~700 w/m^2 at peak) is in the infra red.  This compares to about 530 w/m^2 at peak of terrestrial IR.

Water vapour acts on this radiation, blocking and reradiating it.  Thus during peak insolation WV reduces solar radiation incident on the surface, thus reducing Tmax.

(In WV absorption bands there is ~50% more solar energy at TOA than in terrestrial energy).

Can anyone criticise this supposition?

Comment: I might be able to criticise it as soon as you explain what all the acronyms and named variables are.

Comment: @Asher TOA = "Top Of the Atmosphere", IR is of course "Infrared Radiation", WV = "H2O vapour"

Answer (score 2):

According to e.g. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Greenhouse_gas#/media/File:Atmospheric_Transmission.png, it is clear that the term Infrared radiation, spanning from λ=800 nm to over λ=50000 nm, is misleadingly broad.

Instead, I propose to speak in terms of solar radiation (UV+optical+near-infrared between 300 and 2000 nm) and thermal radiation from earth (mid- and far-infrared, between 5000 and 30000 nm).

While the effect of water vapour on the solar radiation is only small, it absorbs a big percentage of the earth radiation, re-radiating part of its energy back downwards, and retaining part of its energy in the form of heat. Fortunately for the terrestrial life, water vapour is thence a powerful greenhouse gas.

Comment: It's not quite correct to say that water vapor doesn't have much of an effect on incoming radiation. Clouds are in constant  thermodynamic disequilibrium with the water vapor content of the atmosphere and they modulate the amount of radiation that hits the ground with great efficiency, so the water vapor content of the atmosphere matters greatly (if indirectly trough water aerosols) to the incoming radiation, as well.

Comment: This is right, I forgot to mention scattering on clouds. Still, it does not overpower the greenhouse effect.

Comment: "While the effect of water vapour on the solar radiation is only small"
Not according to my calculations.  The energy in WV absorption bands in solar radiation is larger than that of earths.
 
The 0.7 to 3.5 band of solar energy contains ~100 w/m^2
The sum of earths bands (4.5 to 7 and 15 to 40) contain ~70 w/m^2

Comment: I admit that I did not compute the exact power absorbed by water vapor; I believe the numbers of 100 W/m2 downwards and 70 W/m2 upwards. However, these numbers are absolute values, aren't they? Therefore the absorption of light coming from one direction, i.e. from the Sun, averaged over entire sphere area, is only 25 W/m2. I call this small compared to 70 W/m².

Comment: N.B. the integration of the Planck law radiation in Python can be found here https://gist.github.com/FilipDominec/df369cc6a30fafbb4786

Comment: But I am talking about Tmax, driven by maximum insolation, not average temperature, for which what you say is valid.

 
From sun up to ~3pm energy is flowing into the system.  From ~3pm through the night to sun up energy is flowing out.
Maximum temperature is dictated by peak inflow. Since WV is absorbing ~100 watts/m^2 (according to my rough calculations) this means less solar IR incident on the surface and logically should reduce Tmax slightly.

Comment: I am sorry, perhaps this discussion is beyond my capabilities; I just wanted to contribute with what I hand in mind. Nevertheless, I believe that the overall maximum temperature is mostly determined by the average temperature (e.g. 280 K), where water vapor acts positively as a greenhouse gas. The daily fluctuations (e.g. <10 K in my country) are probably *suppressed* by water vapour, but they are of minor impact for Tmax. Sorry if I just took your time.

Comment: Quite.  WV reduces extremes, raising Tmin a lot, and reducing Tmax slightly.

Comment: @Matt I suggest you could formulate your previous statement, including the underlying data your comments were based on, into the original question. This would be helpful for constructive critical analysis you originally asked for.

Comment: There is as good a description of the effect I am talking about here: http://objectivistindividualist.blogspot.fr/2013/02/infrared-absorbing-gases-and-earths.html

Comment: Nice link, thank you. I tried to help you using some general reasoning, but did not read this elaborate study. The downside is that you and me have spent a lot of our time and did not proceed any further from the knowledge you could incorporate right into your question...